# SQL Server - CHARINDEX always returns 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
   CAST([Action] AS NVARCHAR(4000)) AS CastAction, 
   CHARINDEX(CAST([Action] AS NVARCHAR(4000)), N'StatusChange') AS FoundIndex
FROM AuditTrail 
WHERE action LIKE '%StatusChange%'
```

Action is an NTEXT field - this query returns many rows, matching StatusChange in the action text, but the charindex returned is always zero... Any ideas - I need to be able to split this  string to tidy up some data?

Comment: Ah, just noticed the deliberate mistake... I have my arguments the wrong way round in the charindex function...

Comment: ntext is deprecated, you need to start converting these fields to nvarchar(max)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've got the parameters to `CHARINDEX` the wrong way around.

Comment: :-D  oh, sheesh, I really needed this....... some days you just need another set of eyes, even if indirectly and several years apart

Answer (score 8):

You're swapping [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx):

```
Searches expression2 for expression1 and returns its starting position if found.
```

Try:

```
CHARINDEX(N'StatusChange', CAST([Action] AS NVARCHAR(4000)))
```